# How to implement below code in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want page view controller i middle of my home view controller so iam using container view and embedded to page view controller have done successfully in objective c now i want to use the same procedure for swift can any one help me to how to implement code in swift

```
    _pageImages = @[@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpeg",@"5.jpg"];
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
```

up to above i have changed to swift but below code unable to change

```
PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

my convertor code

```
 arrPageTitles=["blue.jpg","blue.jpg","blue.jpg"]
  //  let pageViewController = UIPageViewController()
    self.pageViewController=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.delegate=self
    self.pageViewController.dataSource=self
    var startingViewController = PageContentViewController()
    startingViewController=self.getViewControllerAtIndex(0)
    let viewcontrollers = NSArray()=startingViewController
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers, direction:       UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but getting error

```
let viewcontrollers = NSArray()=startingViewController
```

below this method also not transferring string to setphotoname

```
 func getViewControllerAtIndex(_ index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
{
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    var pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

    pageContentViewController.setPhotoName = arrPageTitles[index] as! String
   // pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPageTitles[index])"
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

    return pageContentViewController
}
```

Comment: what is the problem/ error you are facing?

Comment: @Venkat i have mentioned above

Comment: answer added...

Comment: In future you can try this tool: https://objectivec2swift.com/

Comment: @Venkat tq its not showing error but the method was not working properly

Comment: method was not working properly means? what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
let startingViewController: PageContentViewController? = viewController(at: 0)
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [startingViewController]
pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false) { _ in }
```

Comment: You can use `let` rather than `var` and there is no need to explicitly type `viewControllers` Or `startingViewController`

Comment: i changed `var` to `let` and i added explicitly type `viewControllers` because of the questioner understanding purpose.

Comment: i dont know why did i get 1 down vote for this answer. i didnt find anything wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the **Swift** `syntax`:

Create the `instance` like:

```
var startingViewController:  YOUR_startingViewController! //You can access this globally if you have pageControl target for indicators
```

And update it in the `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
startingViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startingViewController_IDENTIFIER") as! YOUR_startingViewController
 //You can use let for creating startingViewController instance if you dont want to access it globally        
//You dont need to create array just put the instance of controller directly like this:

PageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController],direction: .forward, animated: false,completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
let startingViewController: PageContentViewController? = viewController(at: 0)
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```